# Find out who created a certain user?

Tags: users

How can I find out who created / edited / deleted a certain user?

I got a notification email that a new user has been created but I dont have any idea who made it.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the actions `user_register`, `profile_update` and `delete_user`, and inspect the current user. Use `get_current_user_id()` to get the acting user and use …

```
WP_User::get_data_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() );
```

… to get more data about the user creating or deleting the other user.

Comment: Thanks toscho. Problem here is that you can only get the data when they register/update/delete user. How about AFTER they do it? The user has already been created, I just want to know who did the registration. Thanks much!

Comment: You have to create a log. I will release plugin doing exactly this and much more soon. :)